# Get the 1st category of a post?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get the category of the current post in Wordpress:
The problem I'm having is I'm trying to check if the Wordpress post has more than 1 parent categories set.

The code I currently have is:

```
if (!empty($categories)) {
    // This Category has children
    $firstcategoryarray = (array) get_the_category($post_id)[1];
} else {
   $firstcategoryarray = (array) get_the_category($post_id)[0];
}
```

This code allows me to check if the post has one or more categories/subcategories. However, it doesn't differenciates between subcategories and categories.

Is there any way to check if the post have 2 or more categories?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of this logic is that when you call `get_the_category()` it returns an array of WP_Term Objects. Loop over the array with a foreach statement. The WP_Term Object has a few properties. One of them being `$parent`, which refers to the parent term id. If the term is 0 then its safe to say that it is a top level term.

```
$categories = get_the_category($post_id);
$topLevelCategoryCount = 0;

foreach ($categories as $category){
    if ($category->parent == 0){
        //This category is top level
        $topLevelCategoryCount ++;
    }
}

if ($topLevelCategoryCount > 1) {
    //This post has more than one top level
    // Do Stuff
}
```

references:

[Wordpress Code reference get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)

[Wordpress Code reference WP_Term Object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/)